# I want to understand why the data i am passing as props into the React functional component is showing as undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, material-ui

I have been given a ready made react component, in which I need to pass data as props but somehow I am not able to see the props data when I console log it. Can someone help me understand if I am passing the prop correctly .I am not aware what type of functional component is being used here and if the prop I am passing is correctly entered. I pass the same prop to other class based components which do show the data properly.

````js
    import React from 'react';  
    import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';  
    import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
    import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
    import MuiDialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
    import MuiDialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
    import MuiDialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
    import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
    import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
    import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
    
    
    const styles = (theme) => ({
        root: {
            margin: 0,
            padding: theme.spacing(2),
        },
        closeButton: {
            position: 'absolute',
            right: theme.spacing(1),
            top: theme.spacing(1),
            color: theme.palette.grey[500],
        },
    });
    
    const DialogTitle = withStyles(styles)((props) => {
        
        const { children, classes, onClose, routeHappyData, ...other } = props;
        console.log(routeHappyData);
        return (
            <MuiDialogTitle disableTypography className={classes.root} {...other}>
                <Typography variant="h6">{children}</Typography>
                {onClose ? (
                    <IconButton aria-label="close" className={classes.closeButton} onClick={onClose}>
                        <CloseIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                ) : null}
            </MuiDialogTitle>
        );
    });  

``


```The prop I want to pass is "routeHappyData" which is showing undefined when console logged.
In the Parent class component i am passing the prop this way given below```

        render() {
            let {      
              routeHappyData
              
                } = { ...this.props };
            return (
    
         <div>{noOfStops}</div>
                                {<CovidHealthSafety routeHappyData={this.props.routeHappyData}/>}
                    </div>
    )
````

Comment: Do a console log of props only. Do it in useEffect.

Comment: @ZahirMasoodi Still no success

Comment: const DialogTitle = withStyles(styles)((props) => {
    const { children, classes, onClose, routeHappyData, ...other } = props;
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(props);

    });

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props);
  }, [ ])

Comment: Everything else gets consoled except the routeHappyData

Comment: In the parent component, do a console.log(this.props.routeHappyData) inside a ComponentDidMount() and check the value.

Comment: In the component there is no componentDidMount so i created a componentDidMount  before the render but when i console log still not getting the data

Comment: ```console.log("routeHappyData : ", this.props.routeHappyData);``` Check now. If you only see routeHappyData, then go to next parent and check there. (Prop Drilling)

Comment: yes i can see the data after some time when console.log("routeHappyData : ", this.props.routeHappyData); in the parent component

Comment: Now properly pass these props (checking from console) to the child component. To make things easier implement prop type validations. You can go further and implement Context API.

Comment: i m not able to understand what we are trying to do hre,can u explain please

Comment: do you want to pass the props once again from parents-children-grandchild-greatgrand child component once again?

Comment: Check where does the chain break. Test the data in every component. Start from top. And when you find the issue, check if you are passing the right arguments or properties.

Comment: i can use the props directly in the functional component where i want.

Answer (score 0):

You `console.log` it before your `routeHappyData` variable is assigned. Try putting it one line below.

```js
const DialogTitle = withStyles(styles)((props) => {
    const { children, classes, onClose, routeHappyData, ...other } = props;
    console.log(routeHappyData);
    return (
        <MuiDialogTitle disableTypography className={classes.root} {...other}>
            <Typography variant="h6">{children}</Typography>
            {onClose ? (
                <IconButton aria-label="close" className={classes.closeButton} onClick={onClose}>
                    <CloseIcon />
                </IconButton>
            ) : null}
        </MuiDialogTitle>
    );
});
```

Comment: Tried that as well,doesnt help